# Window.location not working in IPAD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

I have a `<a>` inside a div `<outerdiv>` like this

```
<div id="outerdiv">
<a href="javascript:function(params)"></a>
</div>
```

on click of outerdiv I trigger anchor inside it

```
$(document).on('click', '#outerdiv', function () {
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

this is working fine in desktop browsers but not in IPAD

In IPAD I tried `location.href` instead of `window.location` But it is also not working
`location.href=$(this).find("a").attr("href");`

How to achieve the same in IPAD. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GnwAK) is a link to codepen. I have tested on an ipad and it works fine. Since it is in a frame you will need to hold down and open it in a new tab.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#outerdiv').click(function() {
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
  });
});
```

Since you are wanting to go to a new location in the browser, I am not sure why you are using "javascript:function(params)" as your href, but I have used google.com instead. If you are trying to pass some function or other when "#outerdiv" is clicked then please clarify and I will help with that.